# Iframe content not displaying with Fiddler running

Tags: c#, iframe, fiddler

When I'm capturing traffic with Fiddler I'm finding that the contents/src of iframes are not being displayed. The iframes themselves are being loaded on the page. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

More details:

The iframes have their source set to aspx pages and are writing the pdf byte data like so:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfData);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

I'm pretty new to using Fiddler but I can't see any obvious issues from the log.

Should have added - I'm using Fiddler2 and IE11, using another browser is not currently an option.

Comment: Sample URL? Do you see a message from Fiddler complaining about a HTTP Protocol violation? Also, you're not supposed to use `Response.Close()` like that; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/07/16/content-length-and-transfer-encoding-validation-in-ie10-download-manager-couldnt-be-downloaded-retry-cancel.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's an internal web application so don't have access to a readily available URL. There doesn't appear to be any message complaining about a HTTP protocol violation. Thanks for the link - upon changing from `Response.Close()` to        `this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` I find that the problem is resolved and the page loads as expected when fiddler is running. If you add this as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our comment thread, you shouldn't use `Response.Close()` like that as it doesn't end the chunked response properly; use `CompleteRequest()` instead. I discuss this issue in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/07/16/content-length-and-transfer-encoding-validation-in-ie10-download-manager-couldnt-be-downloaded-retry-cancel.aspx

As far as I know, this issue *shouldn't* cause the problem you describe (instead causing other problems) but since making this change resolved the problem, I guess there's some relationship I'm not aware of.